# DevExpress MemoEdit selection backcolor

Tags: winforms, devexpress, background-color

I'm trying to achieve a similar functionality as with `RichTextBox` while using the `MemoEdit` control.

With `RichTextBox` it's possible to use `.Select()` in order to select part of the text then use `.SelectionBackColor()` in order to change the backcolor only for the selected text while the rest of the text still has the same color. Sadly I wasn't able to achieve this since the `MemoEdit` control doesn't appear to have any similar methods for achieving this.

Anyone managed to get anything similar working using `MemoEdit` or has a good alternative (that allows the control to still be able to use the form skin) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried RichEditControl?

Comment: I can't seem to find a property in the control that has the ability to change the selection back colour.